# infinite Area between function and x-axis

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I have here below a mathematical statement, and it is False:

- If $f(x)$ has a horizontal asymptote at $y = 0$ and $f(x)$ is always negative, continuous and increasing on $[1, \infty)$, 
  then the area between the graph of $f(x)$ and the x-axis on
  $[3, \infty)$ must be finite.

I can't figure out an example of a function that behaves this way and the area works out to be infinite.

I find this very counter-intuitive.
Hope some can figure out an example of a function of this type.

Regards,

Comment: How about $f(x)=-\frac1x$?

Comment: @Clayton:  That should be an answer.  It is exactly what was requested.

Comment: Hi there, i think that does it. After integrating it is ln(x), and taking limit to infinity of ln(x) the area does become infinite. I can't believe I did not think of this basic reciprocal function. I did not think of the -1 multiplying it. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As first noted in the comments, you can have for example

$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{x^p} \quad | \quad 0 < p \le 1$$

You can experiment with any given function $g(x)$ with a horizontal asymptote at say $y=b$.   Just make either $g(x)-b \ \lor \ -g(x)-b$ and see if it meets the requirement of having infinite area

A non rational example would be

$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{\ln x}$$

Comment: Hi there, so can one make for example g(x) = 1/(1+x^2), i call it the bell shaped curve, it has horizontal asymptote of y = 0 and continuous and negative if  we do -g(x), but integrating over [3,infinity) makes it a finite area because arctan(x) to infinity is pi/2.

Comment: @Palu yes good call, see the edit

Comment: SO,  as you can see i have created a function that meets the critieria but creates Finite area.

Comment: The integral of this $f(x)$ on $[3, \infty)$ is finite for $p > 1$, but the counterexample should have infinite area. Perhaps you mean this only for $p=1$, as in the comments above.

Comment: @B.Mehta thank you for calling me out on that I've edited it.  Got ahead of myself

Comment: No worries, we all do it!

Comment: Hi the AmateurMathGuy was not referring to his p-series type function Mehta, he started to say that you can use any function g(x) with horizontal asymptote, which I just gave a counter example to.

Comment: SO besides the basic reciprocal , any other functions that can do this. We also have the Gaussian bell curve y = -exp(-x^2) similar to my other bell curve, but its difficult to integrate I believe.

Comment: @Palu there's also $-\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$

Comment: OK, looks a bit different, but it does come from p-series basis.

Comment: @Palu see the latest edit

Comment: Hey AmatuerMathGuy, I really like that one, that is great! The more examples the better to get a feeling for this. I will give that this is the answer! Thanks again.